# Is this text processing code Pythonic?

Tags: python, text

I need to take a line of text (words) and split it in half at the first space following the midpoint of the line; e.g.:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                         ^
```

The mid-point of the line above is at position 22, and the line is split at the space following the word "jumps".

I would appreciate if you could look at the following code and tell me if it is *Pythonic*.  If not, please suggest the correct way.  Thank you.  (PS: I come from a C++ background.)

```
    midLine = len(line) / 2                  # Locate mid-point of line.
    foundSpace = False
    # Traverse the second half of the line and look for a space.
    for ii in range(midLine):
        if line[midLine + ii] == ' ':        # Found a space.
            foundSpace = True
            break
    if (foundSpace == True):
        linePart1 = line[:midLine + ii]      # Start of line to location of space - 1.
        linePart2 = line[midLine + ii + 1:]  # Location of space + 1 to end of line.
```

Comment: If `booleanVariable == True` reads a bit strange. Also consider using `for ... else` instead of flags.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: +1 Thank you!  Had no idea a for loop could have an else part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pythonic is to use builtin functions where available. `string.index` does the job here.

```
def half(s):
    idx = s.index(' ', len(s) / 2)
    return s[:idx], s[idx+1:]
```

This will raise a ValueError if there's no suitable place to break the string. You may have to adjust the code if that's not what you want.

Comment: Didn't know you could return multiple values.  How would you call the `half` function?  Thanks.

Comment: Eg: `a, b = half('hello cruel world')`

Comment: But how do you get the two parts of the line back at the function call?

Comment: @Sabuncu That is what the `a, b` is for. `a = s[:idx]` and `b =s[idx+1:]`

Comment: +1 Did not know you could return multiple values from a function!  Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu You just have one return value, which in this case is a tuple.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: OK, I have a better understanding now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more clear

```
midLine = len(line) / 2  
part1 = line[:midLine]
part2 = line[midLine:]
left, right = part2.split(' ', 1)
linePart1 = part1+left
linePart2 = right
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the pythonic way but a few tips you can use:

You can split the line to half and then search:

```
the2ndPart = line[len(line) / 2 :]
```

You don't have to use `for`:

```
firstSpace = the2ndPart.find("")
```

No need to use `()` at an if statement also for True/False use `is`:

```
 if foundSpace is True:
```

*by @user7610 comment you can use:

```
if foundSpace:
```

And just for fun here is a soulotion in one line:

```
myString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

halfWay = len(myString) / 2

print myString[myString[halfWay:].find(" ") + halfWay :]
```

Output:

```
 over the lazy dog.
```

The best "pythonic" tip i can give you is: "pythonic" way is good until the point it's not readable, sometimes simple is better.

Comment: Since foundSpace is a boolean, there is no need to compare it to True, `if foundSpace:` is perfectly sufficient. From my experience, this is something people who just begun programming do. They get bashed for it, learn it and later in turn bash everyone else.

Comment: @user7610 I did it just to clear a point about is, nevertheless your comment is right and i updated my answer.